# Convert column values into columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in sql table which looks something like this.

```
WORKFLOW_ID|SLOT_NAME     |VALUE              |PROCESS_ID|
-----------|--------------|-------------------|----------|
         47|pm_id         |6355               |    212331|
         47|entry_id      |7722               |    212331|
         47|tecn_no       |T0212331           |    212331|
         47|issue_date    |2020-10-24         |    212331|
         47|entry_datetime|2020-10-20 15:09:22|    212331|
```

I want to convert SLOT_NAME column values into COLUMNS NAMES and VALUE column into the COLUMN VALUES. So the data will look something like this.

```
WORKFLOW_ID|SLOT_NAME     |pm_id              |entry_id|     tecn_no|       issue_date|          entry_datetime|    PROCESS_ID|
-----------|--------------|-------------------|--------|------------|-----------------|------------------------|--------------|
         47|pm_id         |6355               |    7722|    T0212331|       2020-10-24|     2020-10-20 15:09:22|        212331|
```

**Keeping in mind there might be more SLOT NAMES or rows.**

Comment: Dynamic columns is not supported in SQL query. You can use the dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore the dynamic pivot function written by Anton from AMIS. The source can be found here

https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/images/antonsPivoting.zip

and some samples of its use here

https://technology.amis.nl/it/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/

Internally it is executing a standard query against your data, and then fetching the results in order to build an ANYDATA table in order to give you the dynamic list of columns back.

If you're on a more recent release, you could look at polymorphic table functions to do it, which is covered here

https://blog.sqlora.com/en/dynamic-pivot-with-polymorphic-table-function/

and if you are *really* on a recent release, ie, 21c you could use some SQL macros to do it

https://blog.sqlora.com/en/dynamic-pivot-with-sql-macros-in-oracle-20c/